# Almost no apps on appcenter

Tags: appcenter

There are only few apps on appcenter.
I can't install eddy to install .deb packages.
I tried installing a flatpak app and it didn't work.
I saw a few users asking about the same.

Comment: There is a way to install eddy, now I don't have time to answer all the steps to follow, but when I get off work I will write you a more complete answer. hint: you can go to eddy's github and follow the steps there. just that it will give you an error with a dependency. I'll tell you how to solve it later

Comment: Eddy should be available, the developer just got it ported to flatpak

Answer (score 2):

If you sideload a flatpak from flathub.org you'll automatically add their repo, and populate Appcenter a bit more.

Other than that it seems AppCenter won't support deb packages anymore. So yes, you can still install deb programs via the terminal, but I'm afraid you'll then need to manually update them, because appcenter won't do it for you.

[The reasoning](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/p21ruc/what_the_hell_happened_to_eddy/h8jldha?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) for this apparently is that some users found non curated apps "ugly" so now they castrated the whole os for it.

Answer (score 0):

.deb packages can be installed with sudo dpkg -i name.of.package.deb

Yes, empty AppCenter - most odd. Presumably the content's not been migrated over yet.

Comment: no way, just flatpak on AppCenter. i will not see any apt app (.deb) on AppCenter

Answer (score 0):

**Eddy now are in AppCenter DON'T INSTALL FROM GITHUB**

I was able to install Eddy from the terminal like this:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt install valac libgranite-dev libpackagekit-glib2-dev libunity-dev
sudo apt install meson
git clone https://github.com/donadigo/eddy.git  
sudo apt install libzeitgeist-2.0-dev
meson build && cd build
meson configure -Dprefix=/usr
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

and to run the application:

```
com.github.donadigo.eddy
```

If this solves your question don't forget to mark as solved