# Cannot install .deb packages, even google chrome. used Gdebi and ubuntu software center, no results. Eddy also not present in the appcenter

Tags: applications, appcenter

Cannot install .deb packages, even google chrome. used Gdebi and ubuntu software center, no results. Eddy also not present in the appcente

Comment: Eddy should be available, the developer just got it ported to flatpak

Answer (score 1):

Install Gdebi via terminal by typing
"sudo apt install gdebi"

Then restart your pc and open "Gdebi Package Installer" under Applications and select "File" > "Open" and open the .deb package you'd like to open. Alternatively open the package in terminal too.

open terminal and type
"Sudo gdebi /location/package.deb"
replacing the location for the file location and package for the file name. You have to type the full location name, it doesn't matter if you're already in the directory.

Comment: Note ... if you are in the directory with the deb file you do NOT need to specify the full path to the file ... all you need to do is precede the file name with a period slash (./) which is the relative file name ... so basically you can specify the relative file name ... to make sure that you have specified everything correctly ... at the command prompt just do an ls -la with the relative file name you want to use ... if file not found then you have and issue with what you typed

Answer (score 1):

Install Gdebi via terminal by typing "sudo apt install gdebi"

Then restart your pc and open "Gdebi Package Installer" under Applications and select "File" > "Open" and open the .deb package you'd like to open. Alternatively open the package in terminal too.

open terminal and type "Sudo gdebi /location/package.deb" replacing the location for the file location and package for the file name. You have to type the full location name, it doesn't matter if you're already in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in this post:
[Almost no apps on appcenter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28378/almost-no-apps-on-appcenter)

**Eddy now are in AppCenter DON'T INSTALL FROM GITHUB**

I was able to install Eddy from the terminal like this:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt install valac libgranite-dev libpackagekit-glib2-dev libunity-dev
sudo apt install meson
git clone https://github.com/donadigo/eddy.git  
sudo apt install libzeitgeist-2.0-dev
meson build && cd build
meson configure -Dprefix=/usr
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

and to run the application:

```
com.github.donadigo.eddy
```

If this solves your question don't forget to mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

Somebody posted this in a different thread already, and it worked for me:

***.deb packages can be installed with this command in terminal:***

`$ sudo dpkg -i *name.of.package.deb*`